# How to give specified date range IAM condition to give access of the bucket to the principal(user) in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I have been trying to add a condition in the condition builder to give access to the principal (user) within a specified date range. But it is not working.

```
{ 
  "expression": "request.time < timestamp(\"2023-03-24T18:30:00.000Z\") 
  && \n  request.time > timestamp(\"2023-03-29T18:30:00.000Z\")",
  "title": "permission" 
}
```

I can see the bucket content out of the date range. [I can't edit the condition through the builder; I wrote it using the condition editor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NNhu.png)

[I tried making custom role and gave bucket permissions to the role.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqgc8.png) I want give access of the bucket within the specified date range. Please help in this.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example here:
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview#example-different-types

```
request.time > timestamp("2018-08-03T16:00:00-07:00") &&

request.time < timestamp("2018-08-03T16:05:00-07:00")
```

Either escape the \n or remove it and place the expression on one line.

Both dates must be in the future.
Also, you might have another role giving you access to the bucket.